# Setting Date & Time in java

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver

I am working on report generation. For generation I need date&time[time stamp] telling when the report is generated. For this purpose I have created a method which returns formatted date time values such that I can give the name to excel file.
I am getting error at report generation.
My code is as follows:

```
public class Currenttime {

public String getCurrentTime()
{
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd_HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}


wd.write_xls(Auth,"E:\\Automation\\USP_Automation_Main\\Report\\"+ct.getCurrentTime()+"_report.xlsx");
```

ERROR:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
E:\Automation\USP_Automation_Main\Report\2015.02.10_12:18:41_report.xlsx
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
```

Complete code for write xlsx:

```
public String[][] write_xls(String[][] input,String filename,String tabname,int col) {
           System.out.println("input data lenght"+input.length);

           try {
               File excel = new File("E:\\output.xlsx");
               System.out.print("\t"+filename+"\t"+tabname+"\t"+col+input.length+"col"+col+"\n");
               XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
               XSSFSheet sheet= workbook.createSheet(tabname);
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
               int cnt=0;
               int inc = 1;
               for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
               {    
                    XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(cnt);

                    for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
                    {                  
                        row1.createCell(j).setCellValue(input[i][j]);
                    }
                    cnt++;
               }
                    workbook.write(out);
                    out.close();
                    System.out.println("report genrated..");
               } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
            return null;
       }
```

Comment: Please share your full code. This code it not enough to write data in excel.

Comment: Do you have local developers near to you? I would first contact them with issues like this. They should be able to resolve basic programming issues faster for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filename is illegal, colon `:` is not allowed in files names.

> 2015.02.10_12:18:41_report.xlsx

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names

I would replace `getCurrentTime()` with a [timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732034/getting-unixtime-in-java) or a GUID if the name needs to be unique. If you need the date remove the illegal characters from your time formatter.